# PHP Extensions in C: Can you inherit a class in one extension from another separate extension?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

If I have two php extensions loaded and I want a class from one custom extension to inherit the class from another php extension.

Is that possible and how ?

I was trying to use:

```
zend_register_internal_class_ex(&ce, NULL , "OtherExtension\\Namespace\\OtherClass" TSRMLS_CC);
```

But I would always get error that it can't find it. Is there another way

I am kind of new to php extension programming and there are not much docs on this stuff.

Thanks

Comment: You'd probably have to make sure the first extension is loaded first.

Comment: Yes, I've made sure of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own, yes you can extend from other extensions, you have to make sure that classes in other extensions are exported with PHPAPI and that the other extension is always loaded before yours.

```
 extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *class_entry_var;
```

**:EDIT if using below code then using PHPAPI is not necessary

and then you would refer to it in your class with

```
 zend_register_internal_class_ex(&ce, NULL , "ClassName" TSRMLS_CC);
```

Comment: Why add the PHPAPI export requirement if you're doing to use the class name instead of the CE?

Comment: Yes you are right, for some reason I was under impression it would need to be exported with PHPAPI to be accessed by name as well. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Hi @darkgaro After registered the parent ce, how can we call the parent instructor?